# Fire click event on each link with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

With jQuery, I have a collection of links, each link has a `.refresh` class

I want to make a function which fire the click event on each link with a delay of 10 seconds between each click.

The following code fires the click event on each link at the same time

```
function refreshAllPeople() {
    $('.refresh').each(function(){
        window.setTimeout($(this).click(), 10000);
    })
}
```

Here is the details of each links

Each link sends an HTTP request. I need a delay to avoid a "too many connections" error

```
<a data-remote="true" class="refresh" href="http://localhost:5000/person/refresh/3224">Refresh</a>
```

for non [Rails](http://www.rubyonrails.org) developers, Rails find each `data-remote="true"` and overrides the click actions, respectively, with an AJAX request to action links' `href` properties.

Everything is happening in the `handleRemote` function [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js).

Comment: This sounds like very strange behaviour from a users' perspective. People expect something to happen immediately when they click things, or at least see a loading icon of some kind - not to have to wait 10 seconds for a response with no clue that something is even happening.

Comment: @Denis, do you want the first `click` event to be triggered immediately or after an initial 10 second delay?

Comment: immediately, each click send an http request, i need a delay to avoid a too many connection error

Comment: Ah, so the 10 second delay is arbitrary :) Wouldn't it be better to trigger the next `click` event when the previous AJAX request has returned (could be more or less than 10 seconds, but would guarantee there's only one active request at a given time)?

Comment: @Denis, can you update your question with the code of your `click` event handler (the one that performs the AJAX request) and maybe a small excerpt of your markup so we can see the structure of your `.refresh` elements?

Comment: done! I use ruby on rails a lot of the code is hidden in the framework.

Comment: @Denis, too bad that's ROR that generates these AJAX requests, that means I cannot do much (I was thinking of combining an `ajaxComplete` event with the `context` option of `$.ajax()` in order to chain into the next request, but that requires control of those `$.ajax()` calls)... Looks like Adam's answer is the best alternative so far.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of calling each, just call click.  The function you pass will be wired up as the click handler for each element in the results.

```
    $('.refresh').click(function(){
        alert('hello');
    });
```

Then to actually fire each link with a delay:

```
function clickAll(links, index) {
    if (index == links.length) return;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(links[index]).click();
        clickAll(links, ++index); 
    }, 1000);
}

function refreshAllPeople() {
    clickAll($('.refresh'), 0);
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WWCGj/)

---

**Edit**

Based on your comments, if you want each link to fire an ajax request, and then move on to the next one when it's done, something like this should work.  I assume you want to pull some data off each link, and add it to the request?

```
function clickAllWithAjax(links, index) {
    if (index == links.length) return;

    $.ajax({ url: 'foo.php?name=' + $(links[index]).text(),
             success: function(response) {
                //do something with response?
                clickAllWithAjax(links, ++index);
             } 
    });
}
```

Comment: @denisjacquemin - woot - glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I implemented based on adam's solution

```
function refreshAllPeople(links, index) {
    if (index == links.length) return;

    $(links[index]).hide();
    $(links[index]).prev('img').show(); // img tag is a spinner

    $.ajax({ url: $(links[index]).attr('href'),
             success: function(xhr, data, status) {
                $(links[index]).parent().prev().html(data.title);
                $(links[index]).show();
                $(links[index]).prev('img').hide();
                refreshAllPeople(links, ++index);
             } 
    });
}
```